# Where is the Python tox documentation for tox.ini [foo:bar] section inheriting from [foo]?

Tags: python, configuration-files, tox

Where is the `tox` documentation that describes section inheritance?  e.g., for the following, `[testenv:py27]` inherits from `[testenv]`:

```
[testenv]
command = py.test {toxinidir}/test
deps = pytest

[testenv:py27]
basepython = python2.7
```

I don't see any mention of it here: http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example/basic.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the ["Virtual test environment settings" section](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#tox-environment-settings)  of the [tox configuration specification](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html).